# Check custom options of product is selected or not

Tags: cart, custom-options

I have a code to get a selected custom option values on cart page.But suppose cart item has custom options which are not required.So in this case if customer add this product to the cart but without selecting any custom options.

So now I want to know that on cart page,whether customer select any custom option or not.

I am getting an selected option using code :

```
$item->getBuyRequest()->getData('options');
```

But when customer does not select any option that time I am getting blank array like :

```
Array
(
  [48] => 
)
```

Please help me.

Comment: are you need any msg or log?

Comment: I am putting this in If condition.

Comment: Try this : $option = $item->>getOptionByCode('info_buyRequest');

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution by using this:

```
$item->getOptionByCode('option_ids');
```